# Free or Available

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

My main question is how to tell the guy who called you that your available to start the conversation, for example, someone call you for an interview and he says:

> "Hi Gonzalo, Do you have 10 minutes to talk about a job interview?"

And instead of tell him just "Yes" what's the properly way to tell him?

> "Yes, I'm free"
>
> "Yes, I'm available"

I think that *available* sounds only for objects.

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that *available* is only for objects?

Comment: I use "I am available" all the time.  Actually you can turn it into a joke based on the multiple meanings of the word "free" -- *Yes, I'm **available** but I'm never **free** ...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these statements are correct and can be used interchangeably, and *being available* is not restricted to objects only.  In fact, I had to fill out "availability times" for one of my jobs that told them when I could work during the week.

> "Yes, I'm free."
>
> "Yes, I'm available."

One of the [definitions of available from the Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/available) states: **"free and able to do something at a particular time (should be available to meet next Tuesday)"**  Also, looking at [synonyms of available,](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/available) you can see that free comes up as a strong match, proving that they can both be used.

Other options you could use include:

> "Yes, I do."
>
> "Yes, I can."

Since the essential question was "**Do you** have 10 minutes to talk about a job interview" (emphasis mine), replying with "I do" means "I do have 10 minutes to talk..." in the context of the situation.

You can also use "I can" because you are essentially responding with "I can talk about the job interview."